# python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully but not exit code: 1

Tags: python, installation, cmd, pip, src

I just want to install pyinstaller. Why do I get this error? How can I solve? (rewritten just to share)I just want to install pyinstaller. Why do I get this error? How can I solve?

```
C:\Users\name>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached pyinstaller-5.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting altgraph
  Using cached altgraph-0.17.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting pefile>=2022.5.30
  Using cached pefile-2022.5.30.tar.gz (72 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\name\python\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (63.2.0)
Collecting pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2021.4
  Using cached pyinstaller_hooks_contrib-2022.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (239 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in c:\users\name\pkgs (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Collecting future
  Using cached future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2a4wh7cl\future_5e8bcc5f45d445e3acb93df5317e4b5f\setup.py", line 86, in <module>
          import src.future
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```